# Teradata normalize equivalent in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, teradata, normalize, teradata-covalent

I'm working on convertion of sql from Teradata to snowflake, I've encoutered `Normalize` in  sql with `period()`. Is there any equivalent in snowflake?

```
...
select  normalize
id,
abc,
xyz,
period(time,
case    
    when
mtnt = mtnt_bb_l
    and net_bb = net_bb_l
    and DATEDIFF(MONTH,time,lead(time,1) over (....))>1
then add_months (time +1,1)
    else lead(...)
end),
tms
from table
...
```

As you can see, normalize juste comme after select. is there any workround?

Comment: No. You have to rewrite it using nested Analytic Functions. Search for "normalize overlapping periods"

Comment: Thanks that's I've discovered here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/convert-the-teradata-normalize-temporal-feature-to-amazon-redshift-sql.html somehow same... I'm working on it.